# Is there a way to make selenium work asynchronously?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, asynchronous, web-scraping, thread-safety

My objective is to scrape as many profile links as possible on Khan Academy. And then scrape some specific data on each of these profiles to write them into a CSV file.

My problem is simple: the script is way to slow.

Here is the script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException,StaleElementReferenceException,NoSuchElementException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming#intro-to-programming')
r.html.render(sleep=5)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')

# first step: find all courses links and put them in a list
courses_links = soup.find_all(class_='link_1uvuyao-o_O-nodeStyle_cu2reh-o_O-nodeStyleIcon_4udnki')
list_courses={}

for links in courses_links:
    courses = links.extract()
    link_course = courses['href']
    title_course= links.find(class_='nodeTitle_145jbuf')
    span_title_course=title_course.span
    text_span=span_title_course.text.strip()
    final_link_course ='https://www.khanacademy.org'+link_course
    list_courses[text_span]=final_link_course


# second step: loop the script down below with each course link in our list

for courses_step in list_courses.values():
    # part 1: make selenium infinite click "schow more" button so we can then scrape as much profile links as possible
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(courses_step)
    while True: # might want to change that to do some testing
        try:
            showmore=WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'button_1eqj1ga-o_O-shared_1t8r4tr-o_O-default_9fm203')))
            showmore.click()
        except TimeoutException:
            break
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            break
    
    # part2: once the page fully loaded scrape all profile links and put them in a list

    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
    #find the profile links
    driver.quit()
    profiles = soup.find_all(href=re.compile("/profile/kaid"))
    profile_list=[]
    for links in profiles:
        links_no_list = links.extract()
        text_link = links_no_list['href']
        text_link_nodiscussion = text_link[:-10]
        final_profile_link ='https://www.khanacademy.org'+text_link_nodiscussion
        profile_list.append(final_profile_link)

    #remove profile link duplicates
    profile_list=list(set(profile_list))

    #print number of profiles we got in the course link
    print('in this link:')
    print(courses_step)
    print('we have this number of profiles:')
    print(len(profile_list))

    #create the csv file
    filename = "khan_withprojectandvotes.csv"
    f = open(filename, "w")
    headers = "link, date_joined, points, videos, questions, votes, answers, flags, project_request, project_replies, comments, tips_thx, last_date, number_project, projet_votes, projets_spins, topq_votes, topa_votes, sum_badges, badge_lvl1, badge_lvl2, badge_lvl3, badge_lvl4, badge_lvl5, badge_challenge\n"
    f.write(headers)

    #part 3: for each profile link, scrape the specific data and store them into the csv
    for link in profile_list:
        #print each profile link we are about to scrape
        print("Scraping ",link)

        session = HTMLSession()
        r = session.get(link)
        r.html.render(sleep=5)

        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')

        badge_list=soup.find_all(class_='badge-category-count')
        badgelist=[]
        if len(badge_list) != 0:
            for number in badge_list:
                text_num=number.text.strip()
                badgelist.append(text_num)
            number_badges=sum(list(map(int, badgelist)))
            number_badges=str(number_badges)
            badge_challenge=str(badgelist[0])
            badge_lvl5=str(badgelist[1])
            badge_lvl4=str(badgelist[2])
            badge_lvl3=str(badgelist[3])
            badge_lvl2=str(badgelist[4])
            badge_lvl1=str(badgelist[5])

        else:
            number_badges='NA'
            badge_challenge='NA'
            badge_lvl5='NA'
            badge_lvl4='NA'
            badge_lvl3='NA'
            badge_lvl2='NA'
            badge_lvl1='NA'


        user_info_table=soup.find('table', class_='user-statistics-table')
        if user_info_table is not None:
            dates,points,videos=[tr.find_all('td')[1].text for tr in user_info_table.find_all('tr')]
        else:
            dates=points=videos='NA'

        user_socio_table=soup.find_all('div', class_='discussion-stat')
        data = {}
        for gettext in user_socio_table:
            category = gettext.find('span')
            category_text = category.text.strip()
            number = category.previousSibling.strip()
            data[category_text] = number

        full_data_keys=['questions','votes','answers','flags raised','project help requests','project help replies','comments','tips and thanks'] #might change answers to answer because when it's 1 it's putting NA instead
        for header_value in full_data_keys:
            if header_value not in data.keys():
                data[header_value]='NA'

        user_calendar = soup.find('div',class_='streak-calendar-scroll-container')
        if user_calendar is not None:
            last_activity = user_calendar.find('span',class_='streak-cell filled')
            try:
                last_activity_date = last_activity['title']
            except TypeError:
                last_activity_date='NA'
        else:
            last_activity_date='NA'

        session = HTMLSession()
        linkq=link+'discussion/questions'
        r = session.get(linkq)
        r.html.render(sleep=5)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')

        topq_votes=soup.find(class_='text_12zg6rl-o_O-LabelXSmall_mbug0d-o_O-votesSum_19las6u')
        if topq_votes is not None:
            topq_votes=topq_votes.text.strip()
            topq_votes=re.findall('\d+', topq_votes)
            topq_votes=topq_votes[0]
            #print(topq_votes)
        else:
            topq_votes='0'


        session = HTMLSession()
        linka=link+'discussion/answers'
        r = session.get(linka)
        r.html.render(sleep=5)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')

        topa_votes=soup.find(class_='text_12zg6rl-o_O-LabelXSmall_mbug0d-o_O-votesSum_19las6u')
        if topa_votes is not None:
            topa_votes=topa_votes.text.strip()
            topa_votes=re.findall('\d+', topa_votes)
            topa_votes=topa_votes[0]
        else:
            topa_votes='0'

# infinite click on show more button for each profile link project section and then scrape data
        with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
            driver.get(link+'projects')

            while True:
                try:
                    showmore = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[class^="showMore"] > a')))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",showmore)
                except Exception:
                    break

            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
            driver.quit()
            project = soup.find_all(class_='title_1usue9n')
            prjct_number = str(len(project))
            votes_spins=soup.find_all(class_='stats_35behe')
            list_votes=[]
            for votes in votes_spins:
                numbvotes=votes.text.strip()
                numbvotes=re.split(r'\s',numbvotes)
                list_votes.append(numbvotes[0])
                prjct_votes=str(sum(list(map(int, list_votes))))
            list_spins=[]
            for spins in votes_spins:
                numspins=spins.text.strip()
                numspins=re.split(r'\s',numspins)
                list_spins.append(numspins[3])
                number_spins=list(map(int, list_spins))
            number_spins = [0 if i < 0 else i for i in number_spins]
            prjct_spins=str(sum(number_spins))

        f.write(link + "," + dates + "," + points.replace("," , "") + "," + videos + "," + data['questions'] + "," + data['votes'] + "," + data['answers'] + "," + data['flags raised'] + "," + data['project help requests'] + "," + data['project help replies'] + "," + data['comments'] + "," + data['tips and thanks'] + "," + last_activity_date + "," + prjct_number + "," + prjct_votes + "," + prjct_spins + "," + topq_votes + "," + topa_votes + "," + number_badges + "," + badge_lvl1 + ',' + badge_lvl2 + ',' + badge_lvl3 + ',' + badge_lvl4 + ',' + badge_lvl5 + ',' + badge_challenge + ',' + "\n")
```

Things that I have tried:

- headless mode: not very useful because it is not going to make the script work much faster
- using Scrapy: the thing is that there is a lot of javascript on khanacademy's website. From what I know Scrapy is not meant to be used with Javascript-heavy website. I need to do the infinite clicking to load more data (to gather a maximum of profile links and to do the project part scraping). I need Selenium to do that, but Selenium is really slow.
- making threads: I don't understand how to do that and I found that chromedriver/selenium is not thread-safe.

Do you have any suggestions? (some code would help me understand)

Desired output should look like this (but with much more lines):

[image]

Comment: Please put a sample of the desired output. A sample CSV output from one of the links would suffice.

Comment: @Samy yes I have just edited the question.

Comment: You could try it with scrapy and 1 browser per "thread". I would personally switch to javascript or figure out how to do it with requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason this script takes much time is because of the high number of requests it sends, One way for it to consume less time is to limit the number of requests. This could be achieved by using their internal API to get the profile data. For example: sending a get request to this link https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/discussion/summary?username=user_name&lang=en (and changing user_name to the actual username) will return the profile data you require (and more) as JSON instead of having to scrape many sources. You can then extract the data from the JSON output, and convert them to CSV. You will need to use selenium to only get the discussion data and find the list of usernames. This would cut script running time greatly.

Side note: even the modules links could be extracted using the JS variable that is parsed when scraping the main URL. The variable contains JSON that stores course data including links.

Here's the code that does that:

```
import requests
import bs4
import json

URL = "https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming#intro-to-programming"
BASE_URL = "https://www.khanacademy.org"

response = requests.get(URL)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

script = soup.find_all('script')[18]
script = script.text.encode('utf-8')
script = unicode(script, errors='ignore').encode('utf-8').strip()
script = script.split('{window["./javascript/app-shell-package/app-entry.js"] = ')[1]
script = script[:-2]
json_content = json.loads(script)
```

You can extract the modules links from that JSON, and query them instead.

Comment: How did you get ```https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/discussion/summary?username=user_name&lang=en```? Can you give us some screenshots on how to get it?

Comment: Can you add some coments about your code? Is this for python 2.X? I'm currently on Python 3.7